# Django: Reversing a URL with a different template

Tags: django, django-urls

How can I reverse a url but with a different template name? I specifically have to use `urlresolvers.reverse`

To be more specific:

I have one view but two urls from which it could be accessed

```
(r'^url/$', 'view1', {'template1':'template1.html'}, 'access-url1'),
(r'^url_dynamic/$', 'view1', {'template1':'template_dynamic.html'}, 'url-dynamic'),
```

I don't want to write any code differentiating what template to return in the view because I might want change it on the fly.  So I need the flexibility to change the url while calling it for eg

```
urlresolvers.reverse('view1', kwargs = {'template1':'template_dynamic.html'})
(which btw does not work throws noreversematch)
```

I could also just copy `view1` into `view2` and call it with url-dynamic but that would violate DRY.

Comment: Show us what you've got so far. URLs should not have anything to do with templates.

Comment: To expand - URLs map to views, views may or may not end up at a template, and any one view can end up rendering multiple (or no) templates.

Comment: @Dominic, The end result crashekar wants makes sense, but reverse() definitely isn't the right way to get there...

Comment: @Gabriel - agreed, given the question clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlresolvers.reverse` reverses `kwargs` that match those in the `regex` pattern, not the kwargs passed via the dict, in the url.

You might want to use the `reverse('url-name')` variant instead.

For your case it is going to be:

```
urlresolvers.reverse('url-dynamic')
```

Comment: This works fine. I was obsessing about adding the view name while reversing.

Answer (score 1):

If you really *must* use reverse to accomplish this, you could do something sneaky with your kwargs to pass it the template name.

The function signature for reverse() looks like this:

```
reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)
```

You would need your view function to accept a template name/string as an (optional) argument. Then you'd just

```
{% url my.view.function "this_is_a_template.html" %}
```

Comment: I tried that with the template name as a part of kwargs but i got a NoReverseMatch

Comment: you can't use reverse to pass anything that's not a part of the urlconf that leads to your function to begin with. You'll have to modify both your view function and urlconf to make this work.